# Uniform convergence on each compact subset implies uniform convergence in the whole open set for analytic functions

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

> Given an open region $D$, a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ analytic on $D$, and a function $f$ such that $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ uniformly on every compact subset of $D$, then the function $f$ is itself analytic.

Why is this true? Does it have something to do with the analyticity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uniform convergence on all of $D$ is not implied.  However, being analytic is a local property, so since the functions converge uniformly in a neighborhood of each point, the limit is locally holomorphic and thus holomorphic.

Comment: Can you give the reason why uniform convergence on all of $D$ is not valid?

Comment: For example, the geometric series has radius of convergence 1, so it converges locally uniformly on the unit disk but does not converge uniformly on the unit disk, since each partial sum is bounded on the unit disk but the limiting function is not.